# Видимость вкладок TabContainer в asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, asp.net-webforms

Разместил на форме `tabcontainer`, в котором создал `tabpanel`, и поставил ему `visible=false`. В одной из них разместил checkbox"ы. Попытался сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на `checkbox` видимость этого `tabpanel` становилась `true`, но через событие `checkedchange` видимость не меняется.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked==true)
        {
            Second.Visible = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Как можно реализовать это на веб-форме asp.net?

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div align="center">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" Height="150px" Width="205px">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="first" runat="server" HeaderText="Signature and Bio" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="1C" /><br>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Axapta"/>    
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="Second" runat="server" HeaderText="Second" Visible="False">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, судя по всему, используете обычный `checkbox`. Для того чтобы его события отрабатывали необходимо установить `AutoPostBack=true`.

Пример, разметки:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: Понял, благодарю